# Redux Updating Objects State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

counterReducer; I am trying to increase the counters state(object) whenever the button is pressed. But not exactly sure how to update the objects state by 1 (increment) and -1(decrement). [image] Every time I click the + button and update objects state with state+ 1 I get this above ^

```
const initialState = {
    counter: 0

}

const counter = (state=initialState,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {...state,counter : state +1}
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return {...state,counter : state -1}
        default:
            return state;  state
    }
}

export default counter;
```

app./js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import  { decrement, increment} from './Actions/counterAction'

function App() {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter) // pull out counters state which is zerp
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> counter {counter}</h1>
      <button onClick ={() => dispatch(increment())}> + </button> 
      <button onClick ={() => dispatch(decrement())}> - </button> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Action

```
export const increment = (x) => {
    return{
        type : 'INCREMENT',

    }
}
export const decrement = (x) => {
    return{
        type : 'DECREMENT',

    }
}
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import counter from './Reducers/counterReducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'//make global  


const myStore = createStore(counter)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store ={myStore}>  
    <App />
</Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: state.counter + 1 should do the job here instead of state (btw the documentation show exactly this example, you should stick to it)

Comment: Just a side note: there is no reason to declare `increment()` and `decrement()` as functions that expect an argument (`x`) if you are never going to use it. ;)

Comment: @Secan Yeah I had no idea they were there then but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
case 'INCREMENT':
            return {...state,counter : state +1}
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return {...state,counter : state -1}
```

Try

```
case 'INCREMENT':
            return {...state, counter : counter + 1 }
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return {...state, counter : counter - 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const initialState = {
    counter: 0

}

const counter = (state=initialState,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {...state,counter : state.counter +1}
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return {...state,counter : state.counter -1}
        default:
            return state;  state
    }
}

export default counter;
```